# How to set an ID to an EpoxyModelWithHolder?

Tags: android, kotlin, epoxy

I am currently adding using Epoxy 3.9.0 (first time using it) and I'm creating an EpoxyModelWithHolder.

I'm setting an ID and I'm still getting: "You must set an id on a model before adding it."

### ModelClass

```
abstract class PlayerModel: EpoxyModelWithHolder<PlayerModel.PlayerHolder>() {

    @EpoxyAttribute
    var id : Long = 0

    @EpoxyAttribute
    @DrawableRes
    var image : Int = 0

    @EpoxyAttribute
    var injured : Boolean = false

    @EpoxyAttribute
    var name : String = ""

    @EpoxyAttribute
    var position : String = ""
    // Busniess Logic
```

### Controller

```
class PlayerController : EpoxyController() {

    var playerItems : List<Player> = PlayerDataFactory.getPlayerItems()

    override fun buildModels() {
        var i : Long = 0

        playerItems.forEach { player ->
            PlayerModel_()
                .id(i++)
                .image(player.image)
                .injured(player.injured)
                .name(player.name)
                .position(player.position)
                .addTo(this)
        }
    }
}
```

### Data class

`data class Player(val image: Int = -1, val injured: Boolean, val name: String, val position: String)`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `var id : Long = 0` from `PlayerModel` class and rebuild,

(`PlayerModel_ id(long id)` function is automatically generated by Epoxy.)